# File Handling in Heroku App using JSP/Servlet

Tags: heroku

I have made a simple jsp/servlet Heroku app for the following requirement.

1. Select a file using JSP.
2. Parse that file in servlet and manipulate some data.
3. Create a file on local system with the manipulated data.

But unfortunately, java File handing is not happening. I am not able to   even create a directly using mkDir();

Locally everything is working fine.

Comment: Please be more specific. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what specific details you want. I should be able to select xml file on local system using JSP, parse it in servlet and create another file on local system with manipulated data. the application is created, working on local system. but it is not working on heroku .